# Simulating incoming call or sms in Android Studio

Tags: android, incoming-call

Its possible to spoof calls and messages using DDMS in Eclipse IDE but how can I do it in Android Studio? There must be a way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the Android Device Monitor via Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. The Monitor has the same "Emulator Control" tab that you are used to from Eclipse's DDMS.

Comment: Worth noting that the new AVD Emulator in Android Studio now has extended controls and amongst them it allows you make faux calls and send sms messages to the emulated device.

Comment: Sounds nice, but all these controls are grayed out on my Android Studio ADM.  :(

Comment: @ScottBiggs: If you are on Android Studio 2.0 or higher, these are now available from the emulator. There should be a toolbar floating on the side of your emulator window. The bottom icon ("..." IIRC) will open up an advanced options window, and in there, you can simulate phone calls and text messages.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Genymotion, which apparently doesn't allow SMS on their free-for-personal use versions. I guess for this project I'll have to switch back to the standard (and slow) emulators!

Answer (score 10):

Even after reading the answer here I couldn't find the phone call simulator that I've used in the past directly from the Android Device Monitor.

> The following works in Android Studio 2.2.3 with associated Android
> Virtual Devices.

I read someone's note and then I remembered the menu items next to the emulator.
Click the ellipsis button :

[image: emulator ellipsis]

After you click that button the window I was looking for appeared.
You can see there are various tabs that will allow you to simulate a phone call, an incoming text, etc.

[image: simulate incoming messages, etc.]

**Android Studio Early October, 2020**
I still see the ellipsis and other options.

Here's my current version:
Android Studio 4.0.2
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6821437, built on September 8, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.4.0-52-generic

**Emulator Version**

30.1.5-6855416

[image: emulator options]

**Latest Version 4.1**
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 12
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

**New Run In Android Studio Option**
This new Run Emulator in Android Studio Option may cause the problem of finding the options.
[image: run emulator in studio option]

**Run Emulator Outside of Android Studio for Options**

My emulator still runs outside of Android Studio and I see the ellipsis and options just as in the previous 4.01 version of Android Studio.

**Turn This Option Off**

If you want those other options for now it looks like you need to run the Emulator in it's own window (instead of inside of Android Studio).

Turn the option off under File...Settings...

Uncheck the following checkbox...

[image: turn off run inside]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions.  These work perfectly for sending text messages to the emulator, but what about sending messages FROM the emulator?  For me it would be very nice to send messages back and forth between two running emulators.

Comment: Where to find this option in android studio 4.1 emulator update?

Comment: @icespirit Oops. Just noticed I'm running 4.01. I'm updating now and will let you know. posted earlier -->   I updated my answer to show the latest snapshot.  You can see I  am running latest version of Android Studio and emulator and I still see the ellipsis and options.  Is that not what you see on your emulator?

Comment: @raddevus I created a separate question thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538739/android-studio-4-1-emulator-extended-controls/64538884#64538884