# Android studio 4.1 Emulator extended controls

Tags: android-studio

Extended control settings/options are missing in this update? like sending sms, gps settings unable to find the settings any help appreciated.[image: emulator screenshot]

Comment: Too sad there's no possibility to achieve this, since this feature is really great. Hopefully they'll add the access to the android emulator settings very soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling, I finally started my emulator using terminal-command and I was able to see the extended controls. Followed this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201495/6869086

Answer (score 27):

To see the additional options you need to run the Emulator in a separate window (process).

To do so go to File...Settings... and then choose the following.

You'll need to uncheck the `Launch in a tool window` option.
[image: run in separate window]

After you do that and restart Android Studio and start your emulator, it will run in a separate window and you'll see the options you want on the ellipse menu item on the side of the emulator.

[image: emulator running]

Here's my Android Studio version info:

- Android Studio 4.1
- Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020 Runtime
  version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
  Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Linux 5.4.0-52-generic
- Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: It does on Ubuntu.  The snapshots shown above are from Android Studio 4.1

Comment: @icespirit Wow, so that File...Settings... Emulator => Launch in a tool window option doesn't even exist on the Windows version?  That's really not great.  Maybe they'll release it later, but now I'm really glad I"m on Linux.

Comment: The option exists but it doesnot worked for me :(, however opening the emulator from terminal did the trick for me :) @raddevus

Comment: Unnecessary hassle

Answer (score 9):

## Edit: September 2021

Now, since `Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)` you can enable that in settings:

[image]

And you have it there:

[image]

---

## Old answer

#### TL;DR

Currently, you can't use

#### Why

Base on documentation:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations

> Limitations
>
> Currently, you can't use the emulator's extended controls when it's running in a tool window. If your development workflow depends heavily on the extended controls, continue to use the Android Emulator as a standalone application. In addition, certain virtual devices—such as Android TV and foldable devices—can't be run in Android Studio because they have specialized UI requirements or important functions in the extended controls.

Comment: Thanks - spent an hour trying to figure out how to do this until I stumbled on your answer. Hopefully they update it soon as the docked emulator is a great addition to Android Studio.