# Cant See More Options In The Emulator Window In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am not able to see 'more' options for the emulator in the Android studio. I want to change the location from the options menu.

[image]

Comment: Get some reference from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538739/android-studio-4-1-emulator-extended-controls/64538884

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update as of Sept 2021**

> Developers now have access to all extended emulator controls when the
> emulator is opened in a tool window.

**Previous Answer**

As per the official documentation it's a limitation [See here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations)

> Currently, you can't use the emulator's extended controls when it's running in a tool window. If your development workflow depends heavily on the extended controls, continue to use the Android Emulator as a standalone application.

[image: settings launch in tool window]

Uncheck and run again.

Comment: This solved my issue. But the whole point of attaching the emulator to the Android studio is now gone. Such a waste of implementing a feature that's not completely useful.

Comment: @Muhammed-Uzair It's now available in the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

Just go the **File**->**Setting**->**Tools**->**Emulator**

And then uncheck the checkbox and press apply and run the application again this will show you the emulator with all detail.

[image]